# JavaFX how to close stage to act the same way the 'x' button in the window

Tags: javafx

I have a controller that opens a new stage as a popup:

```
@FXML
private void onClickPayments(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ClientPayments.fxml"));
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
    ClientPaymentsController controller = (ClientPaymentsController) loader.getController();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent we) -> {
        clientBLL.retrieve(clientID);
        updateWarning();
    });

    stage.show();
    controller.setClientID(clientID);
}
```

When the other stage is closed by the 'x' button the 'stage.setOnCloseRequest' is executed. But in that stage I have a button to close:

```
@FXML
private void onClickExit(ActionEvent event){
    ((Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()).close();
}
```

It closes, but the method 'stage.setOnCloseRequest' isn't being executed.

Is this method wrong or is there a way to close a popup in a way that acts exactly like the 'x' button in the window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setOnCloseRequest` handler is executed when there is an *external* request to close the window (i.e. not one from your code). See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onCloseRequestProperty).

If it's enough to execute that logic immediately *after* the window is closed, just use the regular `onHidden` handler instead:

```
stage.setOnHidden((WindowEvent we) -> {
    clientBLL.retrieve(clientID);
    updateWarning();
});
```

If you really need to use the `onCloseRequest` handler (e.g. because you might want to veto the close), just move your close logic to a method and invoke it from both types of request to close the window.

```
public void doClose() {
    clientBLL.retrieve(clientID);
    updateWarning();
}

@FXML
private void onClickExit(ActionEvent event){
    doClose();
    ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
}
```

and

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent we) -> {
    controller.doClose();
});
```